# How does one read a file from a folder in a main program in Java using command line arguments?

Tags: directory, command-line-arguments

I have to pass a folder as an argument in the main method and then read the contents of a file in that folder.

To be specific, I have a folder named "1010", inside that folder is another subfolder named "Oblig", and inside "Oblig" is the file "metadata.csv" which contains the names of several files inside "Oblig" that I have to read.

My problem is, I don't know how to correctly write the folder path in the terminal, how to send the folder path as an argument to a method, and how to make that method read a specific file from that folder.

I have tried searching, but I can't find anything that solves my problem in the way that is required in my task.

I try to divide the problem in to smaller pieces, so first I want to successfully get the folder path.

This is what I have written so far:

````
public class TestFilLesing{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String folderPath = null;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            folderPath = args[0];
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file path provided.");
        }

    }

}```

And this is what I wrote in the terminal:
````

java TestFilLesing "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\1010\Oblig»

```
I don't know what to do from here. I want to test this on a simple method that could access metadata.csv through the folder path provided, and to see if it works, print out the lines in metadata.csv.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program works so far.
You have to read the file into an InputStream (no exception handling provided...):

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestFilLesing{

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        String folderPath = null;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            folderPath = args[0];
            System.out.println("Searching for file in " + folderPath);
            File file = new File(folderPath + "/metadata.csv");
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] bytes = stream.readAllBytes();
            String string = new String(bytes);
            System.out.println(string);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file path provided.");
        }
    }
}
```